# spring configuration file validation

Tags: xml, spring, validation, configuration-files

I've noticed this behavior in the processing of spring configuration files.
I have 2 errors in my config file:

- one syntax (well format) error, say a mispelled closing tag (tryed with "html" tag)
- a "namespace" (validation) error (tryed a wrong path to security namespace)

Since the xml is not valid, i thought that the first error that the runtime environement returned were the validation error.
That's not true (spring 3.0.2 with security 3.0.2).
It first returns:

> The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'http'

then, when i fixed this first error, i get (what I was expecting as first):

> The element type "http" must be terminated by the matching end-tag ""

So what can be said about the syntax check? It seems that the process of syntax check is not performed as a preliminar step, but checking and validation are "interlaced". Every tag is first checked then validated. Is it right? Is it implementation-dependent?

PS: My faulty xml (notice the two errors in schema location and in http closing tag):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsdFIRSTERROR">

<http>
    <form-login />
    <http-basic />
    <logout />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
</SECONDERRORhttp>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="myuser" password="mysecret" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right that the "syntax check" and validation aren't two separate steps. Spring uses a streaming XML parser for efficiency. That kind of parser typically identifies an error exactly when it reaches the offending element, not before or after.